# Access built-in cameras full feed on MacBook Pro 14" (2021)

Tags: macbook-pro, monterey, camera

While using FaceTime on a MacBook Pro 14" (2021), when I click the rotate image button I've noticed it doesn't just crop the video like my old mac. It can show more above and below.

Here is two pics for comparison. I didn't moved anything, just clicked rotate.

[image: horizontal] [image: vertical]

Using Photo Booth or [OBS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBS_Studio) I cannot access this "extra" feed/pixels. They can only access the horizontal video feed.

## Is it possible to get this data? If so, how?

---

**As a follow up question:** Does the camera just capture vertical and horizontal? So what about the corner areas? (Shown in the image below.)

[image: A diagram looking like the symbol plus]

Comment: There is a new feature on iPad that allows the camera to track your face to keep it more in center.  It might be the same thing here - my Mac is not new enough.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes. Most likely, Apple added this for better UX. Maybe in the future they will do something with it.

Comment: Centre Stage-capable camera isn't on any Mac yet, only iPads & Studio Display. https://support.apple.com/HT212315

Comment: I'm on a much older Mac with 3rd party camera. From what I can see, FT captures 16:9 horizontal, but FT defaults to a pillar-box crop from the centre of that, presented portrait, as though it's expecting to talk to a phone. It changes its mind if you connect to a landscape device, as they answer. I don't have a Rotate option to test, but your "corners" probably don't exist, the full image is not square.